# Why is my Lambda function exiting before completing request?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I have the following Lambda function, which I have written by following a PluralSight tutorial [I have a very little knowledge of js. Doing it for learning the API Gateway <--> Lambda tutorial]

I have written the exact same function, with just `{}` as the test json:

```
var faker = require('faker');

exports.handler = function(event, context){
    var inventory = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var shoe = {};
        var shoeType = getShoeType();
        shoe.name = getShoeName(shoeType);
        shoe.color = getShoeColor();
        shoe.description = getShoeDescription(showType);
        shoe.size = getShoeSize();
        shoe.price = getShoePrice();

        inventory.push(shoe);
    }

    context.succeed(inventory);
}

function getShoeName(showType){
    return faker.company.catchPhraseNoun() + " " + faker.company.catchPhraseDescriptor() + 
    " " + showType;
}

function getShoeColor(){
    return faker.commerce.color();
}

function getShoeDescription(shoeType){
    return "A(n)" + faker.commerce.productAdjective() + ", " + faker.commerce.productAdjective() + 
    " " + shoeType + "made from the finest " + faker.commerce.productMaterial() + "designed for the " +
    faker.commerce.bsBuzz() + " individual!";
}

function getShoeSize(){
    return getNum(1, 13);
}

function getShoePrice(){
    return faker.commerce.price();
}


function getShoeType(){
    var shoeType = [
    "running shoes",
    "training shoes",
    "tennis shoe",
    "cricket shoe",
    "other shoe"
    ]
    return shoeType[getNum(0, 5)];
}

function getNum(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;
}
```

However, Lambda is giving this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: e5566a3c-1df8-11e7-8b71-d961323b4fcf Process exited before completing request"
}
```

I have checked the placement of my `context.succeed()` too, and it's perfectly alright.

**So, where did I go wrong?**

Comment: Those faker calls probably take a bit of time to return.  Not familiar with amazon lambdas, but if they're like azure functions, you are time limited.  Are you just taking too long?  You can try replacing the faker code with hard-coded values and test that theory out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error I see is in your `getShoeType()` function. This function has an array of 5 shoe types (array indexes 0 through 4).

But due to the arguments you pass to your random number function, it returns values from 0 to 5. So when the random number function returns a 5, it generates an error b/c the last element of the show type array is at index 4, not 5.

**EDIT**: On further review, this may not cause the function to exit before completing the request  ... but you might see "undefined" in the string that is returned by `getShoeName()`.

**EDIT #2**
Another error is that you're passing an undefined variable `showType` (instead of `shoeType`) to the `getShoeDescription()` function.

Not seeing the real errors that occur is one of the things that I found frustrating when working with AWS Lambda. I eventually started using the Serverless framework, which has the nice benefit of letting you run your Lamdba function locally -- if you do that, you will get much better error messages.